# How do I UNinstall and run a ROS Package?

Tags: ros, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ROS package and I want to remove it to create a new one with the same name and same nodes. I'm using ROS FUERTE

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191976/how-do-i-uninstall-and-run-a-ros-package?/) by [Richard](https://answers.ros.org/users/20135/richard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-09-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Type `sudo apt-get remove ros-fuerte-package_name` in the terminal if you have installed a Debian package. Delete the folder otherwise.

---

Originally posted by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) with karma: 231 on 2014-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-07-02**:
How do you do it from a source installation that doesn't use apt?

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2016-10-27**:
Just delete the folder of the package.